# RegOpenKeyEx returns error code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, fonts, registry

I am having trouble opening a registry key with the RegOpenKeyEx function.  The particular program I am writing installs fonts onto a computer, and they must be added to the registry to remain installed after a reboot.  I am brand new to using the registry, so I have been looking much up, but I have run into a problem.  Here is an example that shows the arguments I am sending to RegOpenKeyEx:

```
int main() {
    HKEY key;
    long code = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Fonts", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);

    if(code != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        std::cout << code << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

RegCloseKey(key);
return 0;
}
```

The function returns 1 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION).  However, the following does work, and returns 0:

```
HKEY key;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, NULL, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
```

I do not know how to proceed, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I confirmed with regedit that the key does exist.  It seems that if the second argument to RegOpenKeyEx is anything other than NULL, it returns error code 2.

EDIT 2: I have tried multiple solutions, including using the TEXT() function on the subkey and changing the access rights to KEY_SET_VALUE, but I still get the same error.  I also tried using RegCreateKeyEx.  Strangely, I still get error code 2, though sometimes I get error code 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICENT_BUFFER).

EDIT 3: I changed the error handling so it directly uses the return value of the function instead of GetLastError().  I now get error code 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED).

Comment: Have you verified in Regedit that this key actually exists? There's no such key on my Windows 10 system, either under the normal registry or the WOW6432Node redirect.

Comment: @MrEricSir it is the Registry key mentioned in the [`AddFontResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326.aspx) documentation and also [Font Installation and Deletion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144833.aspx). It is meant to refer to fonts that are installed outside of the `%windir%\fonts` folder. If you have no such fonts, it is possible the key never gets created

Comment: The error code is clear. File not found. That path does not exist. What more explanation do you need?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Best guess in the meantime: you're ignoring a warning message from the compiler about an invalid argument to RegOpenKeyEx, caused by providing a narrow string instead of a wide string.  (Try making it `L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft...`)

Comment: The error code could not be more clear. The system is more trust worthy than you. I believe the system is right.

Comment: Your error handling is wrong.  RegOpenKeyEx() doesn't set the last error code, so the return value of GetLastError() is meaningless.  The *actual* error code is the return value from RegOpenKeyEx().

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for letting me know I was handling the error in the wrong way.  I now receive error code 1 from the function, but I still do not know how to resolve the error.

Comment: Sorry, but that's still wrong: you need brackets around the assignment, or split the assignment and the comparison into two separate lines.  As currently written, `code` will be set to the the result of the comparison, i.e., either `true` or `false`.  C++ interprets `a = b != c` as `a = (b != c)` whereas you want `(a = b) != c`.

Comment: (The actual error code is most likely to be 5, access denied, probably because the program is not being run with elevated privileges.)

Comment: My bad, I changed it and I do receive error code 5.  I searched how to make the program request admin privileges, but so far the solution I found does not work (changing the manifest file properties in the program properties window).  Any advice would be appreciated as I continue my search.

Comment: You might need to do a clean rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeyw

> The RegOpenKey function uses the default security access mask to open a key. If opening the key requires a different access right, the function fails, returning ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. An application should use the RegOpenKeyEx function to specify an access mask in this situation.

So this probably means that you actually don' have access to the key.

Following links in the page above, I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights

that says:

> To view the current access rights for a key, including the predefined keys, use the Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe). After navigating to the desired key, go to the Edit menu and select Permissions.

For the key that I had personnally had trouble with, I had the following:

[image: Key permission]

Since I'm not there, I can't access it ... (Even though I'm an admin, maybe it requires admin rights)

If it's a one-system issue, you can just change it in regedit.

If you need it for a software you're making, you'll have to find another way, maybe a script that needs to request admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

For what ever its worth, I was having the same problems of getting error code = 5, Access is denied.
Within the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE area, I was attempting to use the Regcreatekeyex, and RegOpenKeyEx and related functions to open and 
write data to the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE area registry --- and had no success.  So I tried using the HKEY_CURRENT_USER area, and now I'm 
having success in openning and writing data to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER area registry, with verifible success  I'm seeing success, 
even thought I'm not writing data in the area that I would of liked to. It sounds like  the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE area is kinda off limits.

Answer (score -2):

The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` pseudo key handle points to the key named `\Registry\Machine` which serves as one of mounting points for registry hives. I doubt you can open this key, or enumerate its subkeys, via standard Windows API, such as `RegOpenKeyEx`. Maybe, native APIs (`NtOpenKey`) would work.

You can create a subkey under the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` key by calling the `RegLoadKey` function. If you need to enumerate such subkeys, you can look at values under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist`; value names tell you the registry path – those beginning with `\Registry\Machine` are the subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

`HKEY_USERS` probably shows the same behavior.